# MultiClient Socket.io/Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

So what I want to do is to make Index (for example) to send messages to Index2, The reason I want to do this is so that I can have two different messaging clients. Is there any way to do this? for example lets say Index is the controller and Index2 is the game.

**Here is my code for index and Index2:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
        var $messageBox = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');

        $messageForm.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
            $messageBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data) {
            $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Server side:**

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/:index', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/Index.html', '/index2.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use "rooms" for that. Look at the socket.io docs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, but can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you connect the socket to the same place on each client, they will send messages to each other ([docs](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)).

```
var socket = io("https://my.domain.com/shared")
```

Use rooms / namespaces on the server ([docs](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)).

```
serverio.of('/shared')
```

Comment: So the
var socket = io("https://my.domain.com/shared")
replaces the
var socket = io.connect();
on the Index2? Or does it replace on both index and index2?
Also where does the "serverio.of('/shared')" go in the app.js file? Thanks

Comment: `io()` is a shortcut for `io.connect()`. The server io goes in your server javascript (maybe called `app.js`?)

Comment: Hi, Aj 
Can you show me where to put the two lines of code?
Im not exactly sure where in the document to put them,
Thanks

Comment: Put your code (w/e you have) online somewhere and give a link. More than happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help AJ! I've figured it out. I'll make sure to show you the finished project!